# The pgAdmin 4 always throw sqlalchemy error while opening it

Tags: windows, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

When I  try to start pgadmin it always show sqlalchemy error .
I am using latest version of pgadmin and on windows
Tried using older version but all have same problem

Here is tracebook of error

```
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\rishu\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\python.exe -s C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
  - APPDATA: C:\Users\rishu\AppData\Roaming
  - CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \\.\pipe\crashpad_1536_DOVQUCMVUYAPISQG
  - CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|Whoa! NW.js has crashed. Relaunch now?|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
  - CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
  - CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  - COMPUTERNAME: DESKTOP-1AQJ5O2
  - ComSpec: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
  - DriverData: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
  - HOMEDRIVE: C:
  - HOMEPATH: \Users\rishu
  - LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\rishu\AppData\Local
  - LOGONSERVER: \\DESKTOP-1AQJ5O2
  - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 4
  - OneDrive: C:\Users\rishu\OneDrive
  - OneDriveConsumer: C:\Users\rishu\OneDrive
  - OS: Windows_NT
  - Path: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\rishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\rishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\rishu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\rishu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\src\flutter\bin;
  - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
  - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: eed0d314-16dc-4a9c-a47e-52637ac085c9
  - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 5050
  - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
  - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
  - PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 126 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel
  - PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
  - PROCESSOR_REVISION: 7e05
  - ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
  - ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
  - ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
  - ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
  - PSModulePath: C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
  - PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
  - SESSIONNAME: Console
  - SystemDrive: C:
  - SystemRoot: C:\WINDOWS
  - TEMP: C:\Users\rishu\AppData\Local\Temp
  - TMP: C:\Users\rishu\AppData\Local\Temp
  - USERDOMAIN: DESKTOP-1AQJ5O2
  - USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: DESKTOP-1AQJ5O2
  - USERNAME: rishu
  - USERPROFILE: C:\Users\rishu
  - windir: C:\WINDOWS
--------------------------------------------------------
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: comment

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 98, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 365, in create_app
    db_upgrade(app)
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\web\pgadmin\setup\db_upgrade.py", line 25, in db_upgrade
    flask_migrate.upgrade(migration_folder)
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\flask_migrate\__init__.py", line 96, in wrapped
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\flask_migrate\__init__.py", line 271, in upgrade
    command.upgrade(config, revision, sql=sql, tag=tag)
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\alembic\command.py", line 294, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\alembic\script\base.py", line 490, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, "env.py")
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\pyfiles.py", line 97, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\alembic\util\compat.py", line 182, in load_module_py
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\web\pgadmin\setup\..\..\migrations\env.py", line 93, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\web\pgadmin\setup\..\..\migrations\env.py", line 86, in run_migrations_online
    context.run_migrations()
  File "<string>", line 8, in run_migrations
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\environment.py", line 813, in run_migrations
    self.get_context().run_migrations(**kw)
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\alembic\runtime\migration.py", line 561, in run_migrations
    step.migration_fn(**kw)
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\web\migrations\versions\09d53fca90c7_.py", line 40, in upgrade
    db.engine.execute(
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2235, in execute
    return connection.execute(statement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1003, in execute
    return self._execute_text(object_, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1172, in _execute_text
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\rishu\Downloads\v5\python\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate column name: comment
[SQL: ALTER TABLE server ADD COLUMN comment TEXT(1024)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

I had checked this(http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8) and tried reinstalling many times cant fix issues

Someone please help in this issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was fixed by deleting entire pgadmin folder
here is path

`"C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin"`

Comment: I was facing the same issues, It was resolved by your solution. Thanks